# Couldn't deploy Spring Boot v2 Gradle application to AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, gradle, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Spring Boot Application (v2.0.2) with Gradle (v4.5). I'm trying to deploy my application to AWS beanstalk but keep getting this error -

`Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle 4.0 or later. The current version is Gradle 2.7`

This is my Buildfile

`build: gradle build`

I'm not sure how to use Gradle 4.0 or later with AWS.

Note when I change the build script to `./gradlew build` I get `PERMISSION DENIED` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a few months and I'm answering how I maneuvered this setback, just in case someone else needs help with this.

Turns out it was not possible to use latest gradle version with AWS EB. So I rewrote my gradle scripts to be compatible with v2.7.

If you're looking to deploy the latest Spring Boot App with AWS, you're better off with a Docker setup with EC2 than EB. It took me quite some time to figure it all out with EB and was confronted with a lot of limitations as I had extensive environment specific configurations.